# How can I make sure that a DirectDraw surface has a correct file format?

Tags: c#, .net, binaryfiles, dds-format

I need to make a simple check if a dds file is of valid format. I just need to do a general check of the dds file, so I do not need to check if it is a dxt1, dxt5, dx10 etc. For example if I have a png image and I rename the extensions to .dds the dds format will ofcourse be wrong and I would then need to tell the user that he is trying to use a dds file with a wrong format. However if I have a dds that indeed has a correct file format I will not need to do any further investigation since I do not care of what type of dds file it is (at this moment). So I do only have to read the parts of the dds file that will stay the same on ALL dds files. 
I'm thinking I could read the dds header and magic number in some way. 
I have to do the same validation for a png file and there I am reading the png header like this:

```
    var png = new byte[] { 0x89, 0x50, 0x4e, 0x47, 0x0D, 0x0A, 0x1A, 0x0A }
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileToCheck, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
               if (fs.Length > buffer.Length)
                 {
                   fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                   fs.Position = (int)fs.Length - endBuffer.Length;
                   fs.Read(bufferEnd, 0, endBuffer.Length);
                 }

               fs.Close();
            } 
    for (int i = 0; i < png.Length; i++)
        {
            if (buffer[i] != png[i])
                return false;
        }

    return true;
```

And I was looking if there is a similiar way to check the format of a dds file. I am new to this and the problem I am having is to know what bytes in the dds file that will always be the same for all dds files (so that I can check these bytes to see if the dds format is valid) and how I can implement the code in a simple way to check the dds format. Any help will be appreciated.

Edit:
So thanks to @NaCl I have got the first part of the question answered. I now know what parts in the dds file that is required but I do not know how to locate it in the dds file. I have opened a lot of dds files with a hex editor but I am not very good at reverse engineering so I can't understand where the bytes that I need to check is located which will furthermore make me not to know how I can implement code to search for bytes at the specified positions (which I can do with the png file since I found much more document about that file) since I do not know at what position to go to.

If anybody can Point me in the right direction or help me in some other way I would appreciate it very much . Thanks.

Comment: By DDS you mean DirectDraw Surface, am I right?

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: This may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddds/dds-header

Comment: That is helpfull thanks. But if I would open a dds file in a hex editor for example I would not know at what position DDSD_PIXELFORMAT so I do not know how to write code to read the bytes in that position. In the webpage I can see I row with the header "value" that has a bunch of columns but I guess that won't tell me the position in the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to be done with a file that has a header is to check for its magic numbers (if any is given on documentation), in case of [DDS file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddds/dx-graphics-dds-pguide#dds-file-layout), the magic number is `0x44445220` which is equal to `"DDS "` in "plain text".

After that, just deal with the specs. Everything (excepting magic number) is stored in little endian format, so be careful when dealing with bytes, according to Microsoft, the [definition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/direct3ddds/dds-header) of the DDS header is (C++):

```
typedef struct {
  DWORD           dwSize;                 /* Always equal to 124 */
  DWORD           dwFlags;
  DWORD           dwHeight;
  DWORD           dwWidth;
  DWORD           dwPitchOrLinearSize;
  DWORD           dwDepth;
  DWORD           dwMipMapCount;
  DWORD           dwReserved1[11];
  DDS_PIXELFORMAT ddspf;
  DWORD           dwCaps;
  DWORD           dwCaps2;
  DWORD           dwCaps3;
  DWORD           dwCaps4;
  DWORD           dwReserved2;
} DDS_HEADER;
```

Based on that, I just came with the following code for any "generic" DDS file:

```
public static bool IsValidDDS(string path)
{
  if (path == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(path));
  if (!File.Exists(path)) // Check for existence.
    return false;

  uint magicNumber = 0; byte[] headerLength = new byte[sizeof(byte)];
  using (var fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
  {
    byte[] magic = new byte[sizeof(uint)];

    // I'm still pretty used to C and fread, so here you go :^)
    if (fs.Read(magic, 0, sizeof(uint)) != sizeof(uint))
      return false; // Not even a valid file.

    if (fs.Read(headerLength, 0, sizeof(byte)) != sizeof(byte))
      return false; // Not enough bytes, even if the first 4 bytes were checked.

    // Convert to a big endian integer.
    magicNumber = (uint)((magic[0] << 24) | (magic[1] << 16) | (magic[2] << 8) | magic[3]);
  }
  return (headerLength[0] == 0x7C) && (magicNumber == 0x44445320);
}
```

The code above just checks for the first 5 bytes of the input file (passed as argument `path`), those are always the same as I have seen and should be equal to:

```
0x44 0x44 0x53 0x20 0x7C 0x00 0x00 0x00 (8 bytes)
```

The code above was tested with the `.dds` files on this repository: https://github.com/toji/webgl-texture-utils/tree/master/sample/img, and both files had exactly the same header:

```
iamnacl:~/workspace $ cd dds-test/
iamnacl:~/workspace/dds-test $ dotnet run ../test-dxt1.dds 
The file is a valid DDS file? True
iamnacl:~/workspace/dds-test $ dotnet run ../test-dxt5.dds                                                                                               
The file is a valid DDS file? True
iamnacl:~/workspace/dds-test $
```

You can optimize the code above to perform a single call to `fs.Read` with a size of `ulong` and check the whole thing against this value: `0x444453207C000000`.

Hope this helps :)